# How to type left/right quotes in mathmode?

Tags: math-mode, punctuation

I want to type "left-quotes" and  "right-quotes" in an equation. I tried

```
$P(x):`` \forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \, x^2 > 4 \Rightarrow x > 2. ``$
```

I get

[image]

The end sign is not correct. How to typeset?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
$P(x):\text{``$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \, x^2 > 4 \Rightarrow x > 2$.''}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Suggestion

It is just my personal preference.

Add a space after ``` `` ``` and before `''`.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
$P(x):\text{``~$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \, x^2 > 4 \Rightarrow x > 2$~'' is true.}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

The easiest one will be,

```
$P(x):``\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \, x^2 > 4 \Rightarrow x > 2."$
```

Or if you want to use two single quotes,

```
$P(x):`` \forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \, x^2 > 4 \Rightarrow x > 2. \text{''}$
```

The output (for both of them) looks like,

[image]

For the later case, the right quotes need to be displayed as text, otherwise the output looks rather weird.

[image]

And trying to be pedantic, in LaTeX, opening and closing double quotes are treated as different. Left
quotes are coded as `` (it will the left-most key on the
upper row below ~ in many keyboards).  Right quotes are given by the two symbols ' ' (or you may want to use the single symbol ").  Thus we
have ``quote, unquote' '.  The same goes for single quotes, or `quote,
unquote'.

You may want to see [this](http://www.public.asu.edu/~arrows/tidbits/quotes.html) for further details.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\begin{document}
  $P(x):`` \forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \, x^2 > 4 \Rightarrow x > 2."$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But I wouldn't put math in `quotes`.

Comment: I can not get as your output.

Comment: @minthao_2011: Did you run the above code as it is?