# Closing double quote in math mode

Tags: math-mode, pdftex

I would like to have a closing double quote in a mathematical expression in LaTeX. I found [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135701/how-to-type-left-right-quotes-in-mathmode) which appears to explain how, so I tried the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
$C = `` \textrm{dad} ''$

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately in my case this is the result:

[image]

As you can see the closing double quote is not correct. How can I get proper closing double quotes for my math expressions in LaTeX?

Comment: Maybe you can consider `$C = \text{``dad''}$`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using CMR font, you can get the opening and closing double quotation mark symbol by using the keyboard character itself,

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$C = ``\text{dad}"$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Definitely the same will not work for all fonts, hence should use as per standard structure, i.e., ``` $C = \text{``dad''}$ ```

Comment: It works, thanks. Do you know by any chance why it won't compile in ConTeXt?

Comment: So sorry, I'm not familiar with `ConTeXt`...

Comment: @user32882 ConTeXt does not enable these old TeX ligatures anymore, use the Unicode characters.

Comment: @TeXnician I'm not sure what you mean... mind providing an example?

Comment: I think in ConTeXt the issue is more the fact I'm using `\textrm`

Comment: @user32882 Use `\text{“dad”}`. `\textrm` is something else but in math use `\text`.

Comment: @TeXnician I've updated my answer as you suggested...Thanks...

Comment: @MadyYuvi Thanks but that has nothing to do with what I suggested. ConTeXt (as OP uses) is on LuaMetaTeX these days and only accepts unicode-aware ligatures by default (i.e. f-ligatures etc.). So in ConTeXt, it is advisable to use the unicode characters as I suggested. Your edit does make sense, though not in the context of ConTeXt ;)

Answer (score 7):

I suggest a command for the purpose of quoting a word in math mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\modq}{\mathord}{operators}{'134} % math opening double quote
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mcdq}{\mathord}{operators}{'42}  % math closing double quote
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mosq}{\mathord}{operators}{'140} % math opening single quote
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mcsq}{\mathord}{operators}{'47}  % math closing single quote

\newcommand{\dqword}[1]{\modq\mathrm{#1}\mcdq}
\newcommand{\sqword}[1]{\mosq\mathrm{#1}\mcsq}

\begin{document}

$C=\dqword{dad}$

$C=\sqword{dad}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `\dqword` you enclose the word in double quotes, with `\sqword` in single quotes.

What are the magic numbers? The idea is that in OT1 encoded fonts, which usually the `operators` math font is, we want to use the opening and closing double or single quotes and a lookup in the font table reveals their position in octal format.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Put the quotation marks inside the `\textrm` command.  It lets you use all text-mode formatting.  You might want `\textnormal`, if you want to stop text-mode formatting from bleeding through (such as italics in a theorem statement), or `\textup` if you want the text to show up as bold in a header.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$C = \textrm{``dad"}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Computer Modern sample]

You could also consider using a different type of formatting for the full-word variable, such as slanted instead of italicized, or small caps, or sans serif.

You also really want [a semantic command for this type of variable,](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/553236/how-do-i-format-words-as-variable-names) instead of needing to hunt down every instance of `\textrm` and its variations whenever someone tells you to change the style.